# R no redondea datos importados de Excel?

Tags: r

Buen día, quisiera saber si alguien le ha sucedido esto.
Estoy importando varias tablas desde excel para analizarlas en R, sin embargo he notado algunas cosas, por ejemplo, en la tabla que aparece en excel tiene los siguientes datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer en R es restar el promedio de las celdas rosadas que están a la izquierda y derecha de cada celda azul para tener unos datos corregidos. Suena sencillo, y de hecho lo es, el problema es la respuesta que obtengo, abajo presento el código implementado:

```
library(readxl)
library(DT)
 path<-"//CENAMEP-DC01/mecanica/D1_Docs/Validacion/CL-D1-001_TipoI_TipoII.xlsx"
data_geom_A<-read_xlsx(path, sheet = "Datos", range = "A67:L76",col_names = FALSE)
colnames(data_geom_A)<-c("Cero_Ini0","Posicion0","Cero_Fin0","Cero_Ini90","Posicion90","Cero_Fin90","Cero_Ini180","Posicion180","Cero_Fin180","Cero_Ini270","Posicion270","Cero_Fin270")
attach(data_geom_A)
ParAc_20Nm_0<-c();ParAc_20Nm_90<-c();ParAc_20Nm_180<-c();ParAc_20Nm_270<-c()
for(i in seq_along(Posicion0)){
 ParAc_20Nm_0[i]<-round((Posicion0[i]-mean(Cero_Ini0[i],Cero_Fin0[i])),3)
  i<-i+1
}
for(i in seq_along(Posicion90)){
  ParAc_20Nm_90[i]<-round((Posicion90[i]-mean(Cero_Ini90[i],Cero_Fin90[i])),3)
  i<-i+1
}
for(i in seq_along(Posicion180)){
  ParAc_20Nm_180[i]<-round((Posicion180[i]-mean(Cero_Ini180[i],Cero_Fin180[i])),3)
  i<-i+1
}
for(i in seq_along(Posicion270)){
  ParAc_20Nm_270[i]<-round((Posicion270[i]-mean(Cero_Ini270[i],Cero_Fin270[i])),3)
  i<-i+1
}

data_geom_AC<-data.frame(ParAc_20Nm_0,ParAc_20Nm_90,ParAc_20Nm_180,ParAc_20Nm_270)
prom_geomAC<-c(mean(ParAc_20Nm_0),mean(ParAc_20Nm_90),mean(ParAc_20Nm_180),mean(ParAc_20Nm_270))
data_geom_ACr<-rbind(data_geom_AC,prom_geomAC)
rownames(data_geom_ACr)[11]<-"Promedio"
datatable(data_geom_ACr)
```

El resultado que se obtiene es esta tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y observamos que no hay ningún valor corregido, por lo tanto el promedio que obtengo no representa lo que se busca en el código.

Llegué a pensar que era la última versión de excel, por eso convertí el archivo .xlsx a .xls y el problema persiste.
Instalé la versión 4.2 de R, para descartar que el entorno tuviera algo que ver, y nada.

Alguien puede saber lo que pudiera estar sucediendo?.
Gracias por la atención.

Comment: ¡Hola! Antes que cualquier otra cosa. Los dato que estás mostrando ¿tienen Formato de redondeo en las celdas?, si es así y no es el resultado de una función o no es el dato original, entonces sólo estás cambiando la manera en que se muestran. El dato en la celda no se ha modificado, de modo que R, naturalmente, importará el dato más no el formato.

Comment: En Excel. una cosa es lo que ves (formato) y otra el valor real de la celda (valor). El valor real lo puedes ver siempre en la barra de fórmulas de Excel al seleccionar una celda.

Comment: Yo veo una impresión de pantalla con valores tipo 190.680 y luego muestras otra pantalla con valores similares, por otro lado estas haciendo un redondeo a 3 decimales, no llego a ver lo que seguramente para ti es obvio. ¿Dónde está el problema?

Answer (score 0):

el problema radicaba en la importación de datos desde el excel, por alguna razón, a pesar que el el excel me importaba datos numéricos, algunas funciones no respondían correctamente, sobre todo la función round y mean. Esto es primera vez que me ocurría y lo atribuyo a la versión del excel, que es la 17.0.
Tuve que establecer la cantidad de decimales de salida con la función options(), luego, en vez de usar round() tuve que usar signif() para centrarme en la cantidad de cifras significativas que quería en las operaciones y no en la cantidad de decimales (nota: signif() no me funcionaba bien si no usaba options() primero y sinceramente no entiendo por qué.).
Luego hice algo sin precedentes, en la función mean() tuve que utilizar un vector de los vectores de los que quería el promedio. Después de eso, ya empecé a obtener datos que operaban correctamente tomando en cuenta los decimales en dónde era sensible la operación.
Abajo dejo el código por si alguien ha tenido un problema similar, no es la solución más elegante, pero funciona. Gracias a los que comentaron con la intención de ayudar.

```
library(readxl)
path<-file.choose()

data_geom<-read_xlsx(path, sheet = "Datos", range = "A51:L60",col_names = FALSE)
colnames(data_geom)<-c("Cero Ini. 0","Posicion0","Cero Fin. 0","Cero Ini. 90","Posicion90","Cero Fin. 90","Cero Ini. 180","Posicion180","Cero Fin. 180","Cero Ini. 270","Posicion270","Cero Fin. 270")
attach(data_geom)
ParA_20Nm_0<-vector(mode="numeric",length = nrow(data_geom))
ParA_20Nm_90<-vector(mode="numeric",length = nrow(data_geom))
ParA_20Nm_180<-vector(mode="numeric",length = nrow(data_geom))
ParA_20Nm_270<-vector(mode="numeric",length = nrow(data_geom))
options(digits = 6)
for(i in seq_along(Posicion0)){
  ParA_20Nm_0[i]<-signif(Posicion0[i]-mean(c(`Cero Ini. 0`[i],`Cero Fin. 0`[i])),6)
  i=i+1
}

for(i in seq_along(Posicion90)){
  ParA_20Nm_90[i]<-signif(Posicion90[i]-mean(c(`Cero Ini. 90`[i],`Cero Fin. 90`[i])),6)
  i=i+1
}

for(i in seq_along(Posicion180)){
  ParA_20Nm_180[i]<-signif(Posicion180[i]-mean(c(`Cero Ini. 180`[i],`Cero Fin. 180`[i])),6)
  i=i+1
}

for(i in seq_along(Posicion270)){
  ParA_20Nm_270[i]<-signif(Posicion270[i]-mean(c(`Cero Ini. 270`[i],`Cero Fin. 270`[i])),6)
  i=i+1
}

data_geomC<-data.frame(ParA_20Nm_0,ParA_20Nm_90,ParA_20Nm_180,ParA_20Nm_270)
Promedio_geom<-c(mean(ParA_20Nm_0),mean(ParA_20Nm_90),mean(ParA_20Nm_180),mean(ParA_20Nm_270))
data_geom_V<-rbind(data_geomC,Promedio_geom)
rownames(data_geom_V)[11]<-"Promedio"
```